# iOS Database Tutorial

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I am new to iOS and am trying to learn how to setup a database remotely and make my project connect to it. I have been searching online for tutorial but can't really seem to find any good ones. So I was wondering if someone could recommend me some good tutorials, to learn how to connect my iOS project to a databases.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wanting a simple overview on how to connect to a SQLite database in Cocoa/Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830890/wanting-a-simple-overview-on-how-to-connect-to-a-sqlite-database-in-cocoa-object)

Comment: @Viral Well, he did say remotely, but he also tagged his question `sqlite`. So it's hard to guess what he was really after.

Answer (score 0):

[Ray Wenderlich](http://raywenderlich.com) has some great tutorials for getting Core Data set up locally in your app. Start [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started). From there, it can be as simple as syncing your database with a cloud service such as [StackMob](http://stackmob.com). The exact service you end up using obviously depends on your goal for the project, but both services offer thorough documentation and are a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can start off with connecting a MySQL DB because setting up MySQL is pretty simple. Try [this](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/06/02/mysql-and-objective-c/).

This seems like a simliar question. What I would suggest you is that learn basics of PHP, connecting to MySQL via PHP and read all your database contents and echo it as a JSON, your mobile client can use a [JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025349/is-there-an-3rd-party-library-for-parsing-json-on-the-iphone/4025379#4025379) that would parse and give you valid information that was echoed from your PHP script.

For setting up Apache, MySQL , PHP you can go with  [MAMP for mac](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) or if windows try [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

I have done a small service with MAMP, just echoing a JSON to a client

```
<?php
// Returns: ["Apple","Banana","Pear"]
echo json_encode(array(fruit1=>"Apple", fruit2=>"Banana", fruit3=>"Pear",fruit4=>"JackFruit",fruit5=>"Guava",fruit6=>"Pomogrenate"));
 ?>
```

So instead of hardcoded values you should fetch results from your MySQL db and echo it.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost or host name","username","password","databasename");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo json_encode(array(firstname=>$row['FirstName'],lastname=>$row['LastName']));
echo "<br />";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```