# UITableView Cell - Edit?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to use a **UITableView** to be able to enter a value into a database's field.

For example,  if I was to have a UITableView pointing to a  field within a database and if I wanted to enter a new entry into the database - tap on the UITableView Cell that would then allow keyboard input into the cell which ultimately end up being a new record in the database??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123740/in-place-editing-of-text-in-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but **if something is possible doesn't mean you should be doing so**.

You might ask why?

Well! you are trying to input data from view directly to database, this is a very bad practice. There are many reason for it being bad, the major is efficiency and security reasons.
You should consider using [MVC pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html).

Now since its completely possible, I will explain the idea on how to do it and conclude with links that will have real code examples.

In [`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
add a `TextField` with tag (to get the reference back in future) and add it to `contentView` of the cell and have it hidden.

Now in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` make the cells `editing` property to `YES`.

Then, in `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:`
get the reference to the textfield in contentview using `viewWithTag:` method and hide the textLabela and unhide the textfield.

In textfield's delegate [`textFieldDidEndEditing:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) make cell's editing property as no (yea, you need to keep the reference) unhide the textlabel and hide textfield.

In `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:` write methods which will commit the changes to your db.

Below are list of links which will get you code examples:

[Having a UITextField in a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell?rq=1)

[Accessing UITextField in a custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375442/accessing-uitextfield-in-a-custom-uitableviewcell)

[iOS Database Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915668/ios-database-tutorial)

There are no examples for your requirement 'coz it bit bad way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible....

You can use delegate methods to take data form you cells textfield  to your parent view controller  and then save data in database.